# 1-producer N-consumer queue in C using condition variables

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, posix, mutex, producer-consumer

I'm doing a project for my OS exam. The picture is I have a process divided in:

- 1 thread producer that push messages in a queue.
- n thread consumer that pop messages from the head of the queue.
- 1 thread collector that says to the producer to generate another set of    tasks.

My initial design in pseudocode is  this (if you need real code i can make a .tar with Makefile and all headers...).

- producer

  ```
  while(1) {

      pushTasks();  /* push messages in the queue */

      waitCollector(); /* wait on a CV the signal of the collector */

      broadcastToWorkers(); /* tells to all workers to start a new elaboration */
  }
  ```
- all consumers do

  ```
  while(1) 
  {
      while(1)
      {
          popTask();
          doTask();
          if(message of end of stream) break;
      }
      signalToCollector(); /* increment a count and signal on a CV */
      waitProducer(); /* wait signal from producer to restart the elaboration */
  }
  ```
- collector, it have to synchronize time (imagine each unit of time occurs when all tasks are done)

  ```
  while(1) {
      doStuff();
      waitWorkers(); /* each worker increments a count when it's done... */
      signalToProducer(); /* tells the producer to generate new tasks*/
  }
  ```

But I got a deadlock somewhere. Do you know how many mutex and condition variables should I use? What are the conditions that make each thread do `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_wait`?

Comment: Please, provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Debugging `a deadlock somewhere` is hardly possible without viewing the code. Also, you may search existed SPMC(Single Producer Multiple Consumers) implementations, there are many of them in the net.